# For some reason my zombies tries to go to 0 0 0 instead of the player and I don't know why

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I made it in my script so that the zombies will know where the player is and go after them but for some reason it tries to go to 0 0 0 and I don't know why. Please take a look at the script and tell me what is wrong.

(Sorry if the code is bad I am a noob)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZK_Attacking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public float MoveSpeed = 3.5f;    
    public float AttackRange = 1.0f;
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(Player);

        float dstSqr = (Player.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;        
        bool inAttackRange = (dstSqr <= AttackRange * AttackRange);        
        anim.SetBool("AttackingPlayer", inAttackRange);        
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Player.position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the rigidbody of this script and maybe it will work?

Comment: Could you provide screen shot of unity editor, with your `player` selected in hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code might be `Player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;` return null or you may have changed this variable `public float MoveSpeed = 3.5f;` from another script or editor.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt find player with "Gameobject.find". Instead of it, use
[SerializeField] private Transform player; drag and drop the player object in your inspector.

Code seems correct i've tried it. Some other things are wrong.